# When are enquo() and as_label() required?

Tags: r, tidyeval

In [Tidy Evaluation](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/modifying-inputs.html) the examples show that, in order to use a variable on the LHS of an assignment, we have to use as_label() and enquo().

Yet, I'm finding that the following seems to work ok:

```
addSma = function( data, period ) {  
  colName = paste0("smaCl_", period)

  ts2 = data %>%
    dplyr::mutate( !!colName := SMA(close, n=period ) )

  return( ts2 )
}
```

I'm failing to understand quite what as_label() and enquo() do, and when they are actually required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides support for unquoting (and now for glue strings), the LHS of `:=` works the same way as `=`: it expects symbols or strings.

There is no requirement to use `enquo()`, you can unquote any string on the LHS of `:=`.

When you do use `enquo()` on a function argument, the result can be any sort of R object. It is usually a symbol or a call, but it can also be a number or a string like `1` or `"foo"`. And if the user called `!!` it really could be anything. In this case, if you need a string to represent this argument that you've captured and which could be anything, you can use `as_label()`. It is well defined for any R objects and is guaranteed to return a single string representing the object informatively.

Comment: Many thanks for this.  This seems to make sense, but clearly I'm still misunderstanding a key aspect here.  If I now do "dplyr::mutate(gspcOhlc, yesterday = dplyr::lag(!!nm, n=1) )" I just get a column of NAs.  I've tried it with nm="open", with as_label(), and with enquo() all with the same result (and no error messages to hint at what's going wrong).

Comment: That's because if `nm` contains a string (say `"foo"`), you are effectively doing `lag("foo", n = 1)` instead of `lag(foo, n = 1)`. This returns `NA` which is then recycled to the data frame size. Try doing `!!sym(nm)` instead of `!!nm`. But please note that `as_label()` is _not_meant to be used as column name in this way, see `?as_label`.